# Python algorithm to generate set of teams where players are with other given players an equal number of times

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I'm looking to write a python programme that takes as input n (a number of players) and splits them into two teams of equal size for a number w (weeks) such that each player is with any other given player an equal amount of the time.

e.g. 6 players over 4 weeks generates the 4 team pairings ((1,2,3)(4,5,6) , (1,3,5),(2,4,6) , (1,5,6),(2,3,4) , (1,4,6),(2,3,5)) such that 1 is with 2 as equally as possible as 1 is with 5 or any other pair of players.

There is no distinction between the first and second team and both teams are always of equal size.

Comment: An algorithm should be language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

basically what I did is used a library called `itertools` to calculate all permutations of teams and just checked whether they have been picked already or not. If you have any questions just ask.

```
list_of_players = ["Mark", "Willy", "Josh", "Rob"]
N = len(list_of_players)
good = []
all = []
for perm in list(permutations(list_of_players)):
    if sorted(perm[:N//2]) not in all and sorted(perm[N // 2:]) not in all:
        good.append(tuple([sorted(perm[:N // 2]), sorted(perm[N // 2:])]))
        all.append(sorted(perm[:N // 2]))
        all.append(sorted(perm[N // 2:]))

for i in range(len(good)):
    print("week:",i+1,good[i])
```

Output:

```
week: 1 (['Mark', 'Willy'], ['Josh', 'Rob'])
week: 2 (['Josh', 'Mark'], ['Rob', 'Willy'])
week: 3 (['Mark', 'Rob'], ['Josh', 'Willy'])
```